# Histogram function in pandas keeps drawing a single bar?

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I have a dataframe where one of the column has integer values e.g.

- 124534
- 3318
- 341
- 1275

etc. I want to see the frequency distribution but when I try and plot a histogram of that column I just get a straight line e.g.

[image: hist]

I've tried various values for bins but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Seems like your data has a very large outlier(s) around 2.5 million that you need to exclude.

Comment: Show your dataframe and your code